# Let X be a sequentially compact metric space. Prove that X is disconnected iff...

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X$ be a sequentially compact metric space. Prove that $x$ is disconnected iff there exist nonempty subsets $A$ and $B$ of $X$ and $\epsilon > 0$, with $A \cap B=\emptyset$, $A \cup B = X$, and 
$d(p,q) > \epsilon$ for all $p$ in $A$ and $q$ in $B$.

The definition of disconnected we are using is there exist two open subsets of $X$ that separate $X$.

For the forward direction I started by assuming $X$ was disconnected, and letting $A$ and $B$ separate $X$. Then just by definition of disconnected we have everything we want except for $d(p,q) > \epsilon$. Then I figured I could assume to the contrary that $\forall \epsilon >0,  \exists p \in A, q \in B$ with $d(p,q)<\epsilon$, and construct a sequence in either $A$ or $B$ that converges to a limit outside not in $A$ or $B$, which would contradict $A$ and $B$ being open. But I am having trouble constructing the sequence, or even knowing if I am on the right track. Is there a better way to prove this?

Comment: Let $\varepsilon_n=\frac1n$ and let $p_n$ and $q_n$ be points in $A$ and $B$, respectively, such that $d(p_n,q_n)<\varepsilon_n$.

Comment: Does this ensure that the limit of either sequence is outside of A or B, and are $p_n$ and $q_n$ necessarily going to the same limit?

Comment: You know that $(p_n)$ has a convergent subsequence $(p_{n_k})$ in $X$, let's assume $p_{n_k}\to z$. (You can prove that $(q_{n_k})$ also converges to $z$) That element $z$ must be in $A$ or in $B$. Either way, that proves $A$ and $B$ don't separate $X$.